# directx (sharpDX) applying effect to image on GPU instead of CPU

Tags: c#, gpu, sharpdx

For a project, I have an image that has many thousands of annotations (such has circle, string, line, cross) that I have to display on the screen. Basically, let's say I have 50 000 annotations. Now, I want to draw them my screen using the CPU to loop across all of theses annotations to make them draw using deviceContext.DrawCircle(or line or cross...) Once all loaded into my screen and into the GPU. I want to be able to zoom without having to redraw all those 50 000 annotations on the CPU because this is taking about 1 seconds and this is way too long for an image zooming.

My question : is there a way I can zoom across these annotations and across the image without having to redraw all those components and loop for all of them. My zoom needs to be 50ms at max so that's why I was looking forward to make these changes happened directly onto the GPU instead of going back on the CPU, applying changes and redrawing them to the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a rendertarget|shaderresourceview and draw to it. If so you can easily use it as a texture for a plane for example. This would make one big drawcall and then you can zoom like you want without a performance impact. A good optimization would be to use two rendertargets for draw and presenting and then swap them on the present... so you can work async with them without an access violation.